# Defining custom go struct tags for protobuf message fields

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am new to `grpc` and have been trying to just fetch a `json` response from a webserver. The stub can then request the `json` from the `rpc` server.

In my `.proto` file, I created a message type:

```
message Post {
    int64 number = 1;
    string now = 2;
    string name = 3;
}
```

But I am not able to marshal the `number` field, since `protoc` produces the struct `pb.go` file with a `number` tag:

```
{
        "no": "23",
        "now": "12:06:46",
        "name": "bob"
}
```

How can I force the `Message` to be 'converted' with a tag other than the lowercase name of the message field? Such as using the `json` tag `no`, even if the field name in the `Message` is `number`.

Answer (score 17):

You can set a proto3 field option on the proto message definition with a `json_name`

```
message Post {
    int64 number = 1 [json_name="no"];
    string now = 2;
    string name = 3;
}
```

[link to the docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json)

Comment: I have tried this, the compiled struct field will then have the following tags:
`Number       string   `protobuf:"bytes,5,opt,name=no,json=com,proto3" json:"number,omitempty"``

Comment: The `json_name` option in the .proto file has nothing to do with the generated json tag, but rather with the name used in the official protobuf-to-JSON mapping: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json, which is implemented in the [jsonpb](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb) package.  
[reference](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/998)

Comment: Man, you made my week!
Thank you so much.

Comment: it sucks one cannot actually define the real json tags.

Answer (score 13):

```
import "github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto";

// Result example:
// type Post struct {
//    Number int64 `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=number,json=no1,proto3" json:"no2"`
// }
message Post {
    int64 number = 1 [json_name="no1", (gogoproto.jsontag) = "no2"];
}
```

,where:

- **no1** - new name for **jsonpb** marshal/unmarshal
- **no2** - new name for **json** marshal/unmarshal

jsonpb example:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "testing"
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestJSON(t *testing.T) {
    msg := &Post{
        Number: 1,
    }

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)

    require.NoError(t, (&jsonpb.Marshaler{}).Marshal(buf, msg))
    require.Equal(t, `{"no1":1}`, buf.String())

    buf.Truncate(0)

    require.NoError(t, json.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(msg))
    require.Equal(t, `{"no2":1}`, buf.String())
}
```

More information about protobuf [extensions](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/blob/master/extensions.md)

Answer (score -2):

Here is my solution, which is an friendly and compatible way for adding go struct tags in protobuf/grpc.

1. Fork protobuf-go repo to your own github account, and add a go tags feature into cmd/protoc-gen-go. Like this: https://github.com/hacksomecn/protobuf-go/commit/2443a0ee4696acaa9aa4bf8c2e0586d7c724c645
2. Install new-feature protoc-gen-go into you path. Like: `go install github.com/hacksomecn/protobuf-go/cmd/protoc-gen-go@"v1.28.0-gotags"`
3. Declare message field with an tailing comment, add go tags expr in comment. Go tags expr regexp format is `` (\s?)@go_tags\(` + "(`.*`)" + `\)\s ``.
   Like:

```
message HelloGoTags {
  string Name = 1; // @go_tags(`json:"name,omitempty" yaml:"name" bson:"name" db:"name" gorm:"name" validate:"required"`) awesome name
}
```

4. Use `protoc` compile .proto. Like:

```
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative  tags.proto
```

5. Message HelloGoTags will be generated with extra tags. Like:

```
type HelloGoTags struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Name string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=Name,proto3" json:"name,omitempty" gorm:"name" validate:"required" yaml:"name" bson:"name" db:"name"` // awesome name
}
```